# Grails: how to set default locale when using Spock?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing, mocking, spock

In order to avoid from getting this error:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'proposals.proposal.requirements.requirement.periods.validateEntirePlanFixedLimit' for locale 'en_US'.
```

I need to know how can I set the default locale when using Spock?

Comment: can you explain how you are resolving the message, e.g. using the `messageSource` bean or the `g:message` tag?

Comment: Like this:
**WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().applicationContext.getMessage(code, args, LocaleContextHolder.locale)**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using metaprogramming to override the locale returned by `LocaleContextHolder.locale`?

```
LocaleContextHolder.metaClass.static.getLocale = { ->
    new Locale('en', 'IN')
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be mocked well, How can I use the default one which isn't any other language? I can see that I have files with the name: *'messages_en.properties', 'messages_fr.properties', 'messages_ru.properties' and etc...* And I also have one with name: *'messages.properties'* how can I reach this one using your code?

Comment: Maybe there is some other way to get values from these files?